# how to update state and then render in the function component react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect

I am trying to update the state first and then render the component in function component. I have got the answer to use useEffect hook. However, the document from the react official site is kind of confusing because it states, "The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen." (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) As far as I understand, it says it render first and then run the callback function. That is not what I want. I want to update the state first and then render. how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this is the flow:

- Render the component
- Registers the useEffect's callback function
- if there is a update state part inside the above callback, then registers that
- Runs the above update state function
- the above update state triggers re-render, so the component now re renders again

The above sequence of actions happens show fast you will see the final rendered output. Only one case where you are calling any async action in useEffect's callback and update state dependent upon the above async action, couple of state of rendered UI observed in screen.